# Bootable Linux on CF Card

Tags: embedded-linux

I have a Advantech PPC-105T (http://www.emacinc.com/panel_pc/ppc105t.htm) that has a 64MB compact flash card with Windows NT 4.0 on it. It is a 300MHz AMD Geode GX1 with 64MB of ram. I want to put a 2GB CF card into it with Linux on it, and I am not sure how to do that. I have seen UNetbootin, which I plan to try, but I am also not sure what distro I should even try. There is a touch screen on the front that I would of course want to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CF card is plugged in to a *CF to IDE adapter*, a linux distro like [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com/) will be able to clone itself onto the CF card.

You can start with the LiveCD

Comment: The motherboard has a CF card slot. It boots at the secondary master device. I guess it could be a CF to IDE internally (sort of seems like it at least). Is there a way to load Puppy Linux onto the CF card from my laptop and then install the card? I don't have a CD drive on the device.

Comment: Well, yes CF to IDE is a little old-fashioned. IDE is not going to be in a laptop, but it might be worth looking at the Puppy Linux website.

Comment: Just some fyi, I recently got a 32 GB monster CF card with a speed of 800x or 120 MByte/s. It works transparently with a CF2SATA adapter. Linux boots a couple of seconds faster than on a seagate hybrid disk (that is flash plus regular disk storage).